# PHP SQL updating existing Records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, updates

I am trying to have a webpage pull existing sql records from a table, and use a form to update the empty columns in these records. I can't seem to get the update these records to actually update in the table. I have been hunting all over, and everything I have tried does not work. I believe the issue I am having is getting it grab the id from the table, and using that to update the logs table. I am just learning PHP and SQL so it's entirely possible I am overlooking something very stupid. Any help is very appreciated.

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('there was a problem connecting to the database' . mysql_error());

$sql = "
SELECT Part
     , Lot
     , Qty
     , AnodTemp
     , Amp
     , SealTemp
     , PerformedBy
     , DateTimePerformed
     , FinalAnodThickness
     , QtyPass
     , CheckedBy
     , DateTimeChecked
     , id  
  FROM logs
";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $unapproved = $row['CheckedBy'];
        if($unapproved == null) {
            echo "<br><br><br> Part: " . $row['Part']. " / Lot: " . $row['Lot']. " / Qty: " . $row['Qty']. " / AnodTemp: " . $row['AnodTemp']. " / Amp: " . $row['Amp']. " / SealTemp: " . $row['SealTemp']. " / PerformedBy: " . $row['PerformedBy']. " / ID: " . $row['id']; ?>

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Final Anod Thickness:<br>
            <input type="text" name="FinalAnodThickness">
            <br><br>
            Qty Pass:<br>
            <input type="text" name="QtyPass">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
            <br><br>
        </form> 
        _____________________________________________________________________
        <?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $FinalAnodThickness= $_POST['FinalAnodThickness'];
                $QtyPass= $_POST['QtyPass'];
                $CheckedBy= $_SESSION['CheckedBy'];

                $sql = "UPDATE logs SET FinalAnodThickness = $FinalAnodThickness WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM logs)";
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: First of all, you are only trying to update the columns and not retrieving the data. Right?

Comment: I am trying to view the existing data, and add data to the empty columns.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the output?

Comment: No I do not get any syntax errors.

Comment: Are you actually executing your query? I just see a string. And you should use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection. You should also add the ID as a hidden field to the form so that you know what record to update when you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to execute the update statement you have:

```
$sql = "UPDATE logs SET FinalAnodThickness = $FinalAnodThickness WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM logs)";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Records updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating records: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: I knew that this had to be something stupid I was forgetting. Thank you so much for pointing this out.